# To Unsigned and Back: Casting Pointer vs Casting Dereference

Tags: c, pointers, casting, lua, unsigned

Assuming you don't care about the casting style of the compiler and the machine, is there any appreciable difference between:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int64_t tosigned (void *p)
{
    return *(int64_t *)p;
}

int main (void)
{
    int64_t i = 0xfabf00d0badf00d;
    uint64_t u = 0xabad1deacafebabe;
    printf("%"PRId64 "\n" "%"PRId64 "\n", tosigned(&i), tosigned(&u));
    return 0;
}
```

And this?

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int64_t tosigned (void *p, int isunsigned)
{
    return isunsigned ? (int64_t)*(uint64_t *)p : *(int64_t *)p;
}

int main (void)
{
    int64_t i = 0xfabf00d0badf00d;
    uint64_t u = 0xabad1deacafebabe;
    printf("%"PRId64 "\n" "%"PRId64 "\n", tosigned(&i, 0), tosigned(&u, 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Assembly dumps using `clang -S -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra` for `-O2` and higher show no difference in output. However, I wanted to know if there was a more "correct" way to do it, or if the first method would run into Undefined or Implementation-Specific behavior.

I assume casting to a pointer-to-the-unsigned-version of the same type would be just as well the same as casting the result of the pointer dereference.

*Background:*

I was writing an int64 library for Lua and came across this academic question when doing typecasts for arithmetic.

I store int64_t and uint64_t userdata (opaque C blobs stored in the Lua runtime) on the Lua stack. There are "metamethods" assigned to do arithmetic, e.g., `"__add"` for `x + y` instead of raising a type error because you can't (normally) perform arithmetic on non-numbers. However, the signed and unsigned values are stored as different types and are thus not compatible. I do a wider conversion on the second argument, casting it to the same signedness as the first. The `isunsigned` param roughly matches "does this have an unsigned type table?". The runtime returns a void pointer for the stored value and how you convert it is up to you.

Comment: I don't think there is any difference, but using a function just to do a casting seems like an overkill.

Comment: For an int64 library for Lua, see http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lint64, but it supports signed numbers only. OTOH, arithmetic in signed and unsigned is the same, it's just how they are compared and printed that is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method, casting pointers, is permitted by the C standard because C 2011 (N1570) 6.5 7 permits accessing an object by a signed or unsigned type that corresponding to the effective type of the object. That is, you are allowed to access an unsigned integer as the signed integer of the same size and vice-versa. (It should be noted that this aliasing is a specific case explicitly permitted by the C standard. Many other pointer casts, followed by dereferences, will violate the aliasing rules specified in 6.5 7.)

The second method, casting integers to signed integers, is defined by the C standard if the value is representable in the destination type (6.3.1.3 1) and implementation-defined otherwise (and may trap) (6.3.1.3 3).